# C++ program didn't work in Eclipse?

Tags: android

I have done all the prerequisite setup for running c++ program in eclipse, i have installed and configure CYGWIN and other requirements, also my program doesn't give any error but when i run it then it does't display the out , and it show some errors
My program is

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include<iostream.h>

int main(void)
{
    //puts("Hello World!!!");
    cout<<"Starting...";

    while(1)
    {
        cout<<"Please Help !";
    }
    return 0;//EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

This is what is shown in the console when I run the program:
    [New Thread 6040.0x10e0] [New Thread 6040.0xed0]

Comment: What errors is it showing?

Comment: can U show the error, which type of an error comes after execution.

Comment: You are missing the namespace of the cout, it should be "std::cout" or you need to add "using namespace std;" before the main.

Comment: it shows this  in console after running the project                        [New Thread 6040.0x10e0]
[New Thread 6040.0xed0]